# ASP.NET MVC: Unit testing controllers that use UrlHelper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, urlhelper

One of my controllers actions, one that is being called in an Ajax request, is returning an URL to the client side so it can do a redirection. I'm using `Url.RouteUrl(..)` and during my unit tests this fails since the `Controller.Url` parameter is not pre-filled.

I tried a lot of things, among others attempting to stub `UrlHelper` (which failed), manually creating a `UrlHelper` with a `RequestContext` that has a stubbed `HttpContextBase` (which failed on a `RouteCollection.GetUrlWithApplicationPath` call).

I have searched Google but found virtually nothing on the subject. Am I doing something incredibly stupid using `Url.RouteUrl` in my Controller action? Is there an easier way?

To make it even worse, I'd like to be able to test the returned URL in my unit test - in fact I'm only interested in knowing it's redirecting to the right route, but since I'm returning an URL instead of a route, I would like to control the URL that is resolved (eg. by using a stubbed `RouteCollection`) - but I'll be happy to get my test passing to begin with.

Answer (score 203, accepted):

Here is one of my tests (xUnit + Moq) just for similar case (using Url.RouteUrl in controller)

```
var routes = new RouteCollection();
MvcApplication.RegisterRoutes(routes);

var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>(MockBehavior.Strict);
request.SetupGet(x => x.ApplicationPath).Returns("/");
request.SetupGet(x => x.Url).Returns(new Uri("http://localhost/a", UriKind.Absolute));
request.SetupGet(x => x.ServerVariables).Returns(new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection());

var response = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>(MockBehavior.Strict);
response.Setup(x => x.ApplyAppPathModifier("/post1")).Returns("http://localhost/post1");

var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>(MockBehavior.Strict);
context.SetupGet(x => x.Request).Returns(request.Object);
context.SetupGet(x => x.Response).Returns(response.Object);

var controller = new LinkbackController(dbF.Object);
controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(context.Object, new RouteData(), controller);
controller.Url = new UrlHelper(new RequestContext(context.Object, new RouteData()), routes);
```

Comment: For the time being I went with a solution where I abstracted away calls to UrlHelper so I can intercept them. Thanks for your snippet however, it will save me alot of time figuring out how to correctly mock a Request/Response/ControllerContext.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @eu-ge-ne, it helped me out a lot too.  I've included some more moq setups to use a formcollection parameter used by UpdateModel

Comment: +1 excellent. Though a tip: I use this as a MockHelper and change the response.Setup for ApplyAppPathModifier to this: response.Setup(x => x.ApplyAppPathModifier(Moq.It.IsAny<String>())).Returns((String url) => url); It's ugly, but I get the serialized object back in url encoded form, instead of hardcoding the value returned.

Comment: That partially works for me. Any ideas why I get Controller/ instead of Controller/Action? My test fails because they're not quite the same and yet I register the same routing values. Very odd...

Comment: The `ApplyAppPathModifier` part is the critical bit for the UrlHelper

Comment: How to get the `MvcApplication.RegisterRoutes(routes);` ?

Answer (score 37):

A modified implementation from eu-ge-ne. This one returns a generated link based on the routes defined in the application. eu-ge-ne's example always returned a fixed response. The approach below will allow you to test that the correct action/controller and route information is being passed into the UrlHelper - which is what you want if you are testing call to the UrlHelper.

```
var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
var response = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
var session = new Mock<HttpSessionStateBase>();
var server = new Mock<HttpServerUtilityBase>();

context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Request).Returns(request.Object);
context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Response).Returns(response.Object);
context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Session).Returns(session.Object);
context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Server).Returns(server.Object);

request.SetupGet(x => x.ApplicationPath).Returns("/");
request.SetupGet(x => x.Url).Returns(new Uri("http://localhost/a", UriKind.Absolute));
request.SetupGet(x => x.ServerVariables).Returns(new NameValueCollection());

response.Setup(x => x.ApplyAppPathModifier(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns<string>(x => x);

context.SetupGet(x => x.Request).Returns(request.Object);
context.SetupGet(x => x.Response).Returns(response.Object);

var routes = new RouteCollection();
MvcApplication.RegisterRoutes(routes);
var helper = new UrlHelper(new RequestContext(context.Object, new RouteData()), routes);
```

Answer (score 2):

Building off the answer by @eu-ge-ne which helped me a great deal:

I had an ActionResult that did a redirect as well as had an UpdateModel call with a FormCollection parameter.  For the UpdateModel() to work I had to add this to my Mocked HttpRequestBase:

```
FormCollection collection = new FormCollection();
collection["KeyName"] = "KeyValue";

request.Setup(x => x.Form).Returns(collection);
request.Setup(x => x.QueryString).Returns(new NameValueCollection());
```

To test that the redirected URL was correct, you can do the following:

```
RedirectResult result = controller.ActionName(modelToSubmit, collection) as RedirectResult;
Assert.AreEqual("/Expected/URL", result.Url);
```