# How to unit test a controller that calls Url.Action using AutoMockContainer?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq

This question is very similar to [674458](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674458/asp-net-mvc-unit-testing-controllers-that-use-urlhelper) but I really want to use the AutoMockContainer in my unit tests. I cannot figure out how to setup up my context.

Has anyone been able to unit test a controller that calls Url.Action using the AutoMockContainer?

Comment: Your controller shouldn't be calling Url.Action at all, IMHO. That's for views.

Comment: @Craig, Normaly, you are right. But consier for a moment a controller method that returns a JsonResult, that among other things, includes a url of another ajax method that the browser is supposed to call.

Comment: I think I would probably do this either by subtyping JsonResult or writing custom serialization for the model I pass to Json.

Comment: And what if you want to send an email that has a link to the website? How do you test this link?

Comment: It's a perfectly valid question, there are many reasons for wanting to do this. Have a look at this: http://codeswordsman.wordpress.com/2011/07/22/unit-testing-controllers-that-call-url-action-and-verify-correct-url/#comment-31