# How can I generate ASP.NET MVC URLs inside a unit test project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, moq, asp.net-mvc-routing, xunit.net

How can I generate the URLs corresponding to the controller, action, and parameters (for a given ASP.NET MVC project) in another project (a class library used for testing)?

All I have found so far is **HtmlHelper.GenerateRouteLink**, but didn't find yet how to pass the correct request context and route collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var routes = new RouteCollection();
MvcApplication.RegisterRoutes(routes);

var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();

var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(new RequestContext(context.Object, new RouteData()), routes);

var url = urlHelper.Action("action", "controller", new { id = ... });
```

From [SO - ASP.NET MVC: Unit testing controllers that use UrlHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674458/asp-net-mvc-unit-testing-controllers-that-use-urlhelper/675269#675269)