# Unit Test hitting UrlHelper extension method always fails to match route based on route name

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-routing

... but the same extension method works when the application itself is executing.  The UrlHelper extension method itself looks like this:

```
    public static string CategoryLandingPage(this UrlHelper helper, string seoCategoryName)
    {
        return helper.RouteUrl("Category", new { area = "SoAndSo", controller = "SoAndSo", action = "Category", seoCategoryName = seoCategoryName }, "http");
    }
```

I register that particular route like this in my SoAndSoAreaRegistration class:

```
        context.MapRoute(
           "Category",
           "category/{seoCategoryName}",
           new { area = "SoAndSo", controller = "SoAndSo", action = "Category", seoCategoryName = string.Empty }
        );
```

... and I have dropped a breakpoint on that registration to ensure that it gets hit by the test runner, and it does.

When I run the test, I get an ArgumentException, "A route named 'Category' could not be found in the route collection.  Parameter name: name".

My guess is that we do not need to specify the route name **and** enough route parameters (area/controller/action/category name) to construct the route in its entirety as we're doing here, but I can't figure out where the route name disappears to during testing.  Removing the category name eliminates the exception and allows the test to pass, but I would still like to understand where the route name disappears to when I'm testing.  Simplifying the code like so still blows up at runtime:

```
    public static string CategoryLandingPage(this UrlHelper helper, string seoCategoryName)
    {
        return helper.RouteUrl("Category");            
    }
```

If I dig through the route collection at runtime, I can find the category route, but there is no evidence of a .Name property, nor do I see the route's name ("Category" with a capital C) anywhere among the UrlHelper's properties (apologies for the goofy obfuscation; better safe than sorry):
[image: code snippet]

Does anyone know how I can write unit tests which hit UrlHelper extension methods which reference routes by their name?  Thanks!

- Update -
  I'll add some of the test initialization, most of which I got from [this popular question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674458/asp-net-mvc-unit-testing-controllers-that-use-urlhelper), lightly modified to account for the fact that the application I'm working with is separated into multiple MVC areas:

  private SoAndSoController CreateController()
  {
      var service = new Mock();
      var cookieMgr = new Mock();
      var logger = new Mock();

  ```
  var allRoutes = new RouteCollection();
  MvcApplication.RegisterRoutes(allRoutes);
  var soAndSoAreaRegistration = new SoAndSoAreaRegistration();
  var soAndSoAreaRegistrationContext = new AreaRegistrationContext(soAndSoAreaRegistration.AreaName, new RouteCollection());
  soAndSoAreaRegistration.RegisterArea(soAndSoAreaRegistrationContext);
  soAndSoAreaRegistrationContext.Routes.ForEach(r => allRoutes.Add(r));

  var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
  request.SetupGet(x => x.ApplicationPath).Returns("/");
  request.SetupGet(x => x.Url).Returns(new Uri("http://localhost/a", UriKind.Absolute));
  request.SetupGet(x => x.ServerVariables).Returns(new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection());

  var response = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
  response.Setup(x => x.ApplyAppPathModifier("/post1")).Returns("http://localhost/post1");

  var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
  context.SetupGet(x => x.Request).Returns(request.Object);
  context.SetupGet(x => x.Response).Returns(response.Object);

  var controller = new SoAndSoController(service.Object, cookieMgr.Object, null, logger.Object, null);
  controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(context.Object, new RouteData(), controller);
  controller.Url = new UrlHelper(new RequestContext(context.Object, new RouteData()), allRoutes);

  return controller;
  ```

  }

Comment: You ask about some unit test and don't show the code of the unit test. It will be difficult to help you.

Comment: The test itself just calls someController.ActionMethod(new SearchRequest { searchQuery = "some words" } ); and the action method just contains return Redirect(Url.CategoryLandingPage(wordsTheUserTypedIn);  Perhaps the test initialization will be relevant - I'll append the question itself to include that.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  I needed to pass my RouteCollection into the AreaRegistrationContext, rather than passing it a new RouteCollection:

```
            var productFindingAreaRegistrationContext = new AreaRegistrationContext(productFindingAreaRegistration.AreaName, allRoutes);
```

But that was causing this line to blow up:

```
productFindingAreaRegistrationContext.Routes.ForEach(r => allRoutes.Add(r));
```

However now this line was no longer needed, so I commented it out.  Voila.