# Why is Controller.Url null when I unit test my action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nunit, moq

I've followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/675269/26226) to mock HttpContext, Request, Response and User and set `Controller.ControllerContext` and `Controller.Url`.

`Controller.Url` is most definitely not null before calling `controller.Index()`. However, inside `controller.Index()`, it is null. It seems very strange. What am I missing?

Here's my test fixture:

```
[TestFixture]
public class ControllerFixtureBase
{
    private Mock<HttpContextBase> _httpContextMock;
    private RouteCollection _routes;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        var requestMock = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
        requestMock.SetupGet(x => x.ApplicationPath)
            .Returns("/");
        requestMock.SetupGet(x => x.Url)
            .Returns(new Uri("http://localhost/a", UriKind.Absolute));
        requestMock.SetupGet(x => x.ServerVariables)
            .Returns(new NameValueCollection());

        var responseMock = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
        responseMock.Setup(x => x.ApplyAppPathModifier(It.IsAny<string>()))
            .Returns((string url) => url);

        var principalMock = new Mock<IPrincipal>();
        principalMock.SetupGet(p => p.Identity)
            .Returns(new GenericIdentity("testuser"));
        principalMock.Setup(p => p.IsInRole(ApplicationRoles.DataAdmin))
            .Returns(false);

        _httpContextMock = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
        _httpContextMock.Setup(x => x.User)
            .Returns(principalMock.Object);
        _httpContextMock.Setup(x => x.Request)
            .Returns(requestMock.Object);
        _httpContextMock.SetupGet(x => x.Response)
            .Returns(responseMock.Object);

        _routes = new RouteCollection();
        MvcApplication.RegisterRoutes(_routes);
    }

    protected void PrepareController(Controller controller)
    {
        var requestContext = new RequestContext(_httpContextMock.Object, new RouteData());

        controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(requestContext, controller);
        controller.Url = new UrlHelper(requestContext, _routes);
    }

    [Test]
    public void Index()
    {
        HomeController controller = new HomeController();
        PrepareController(controller);

        Assert.That(controller.Url, Is.Not.Null);
        Assert.That(controller.ViewBag, Is.Not.Null);

        ViewResult viewResult = controller.Index() as ViewResult;

        Assert.That(viewResult, Is.Not.Null);
        Assert.That(viewResult.ViewBag.IndexUrl, Is.EqualTo("/"));
    }
}
```

And here's my very simple action:

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

        // System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
        ViewBag.IndexUrl = Url.Action("Index");

        return View();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the answer has nothing to do with mocking. Both my MVC and test project were creating using MVC 4 beta. I ran into some weird issues with AuthorizeAttribute so I converted the projects to MVC 3 by creating new projects and moving files around.

I must have had some mismatched references, because when I manually removed all MVC and Web references from both projects and re-added them, the test passed.