# Web API RouteUrl returns null exception in test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

I am a bit new unit testing and am trying to use Moq and MSTest in Visual Studio 2012 to create a test on a method for one of my applications. The application works as it should, but when I run my test, I'm getting a null reference exception on the following:

```
var fooURL = Url.RouteUrl("MyApi", new { httproute = string.Empty, controller = "MyController", id = id }, Request.Url.Scheme);
```

I have tried reading and wrapping my head around [ASP.NET MVC: Unit testing controllers that use UrlHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674458/asp-net-mvc-unit-testing-controllers-that-use-urlhelper), but these appear to be concerned with testing the url itself. I am more concerned with testing what comes later in my function.

Is the setup mentioned in the above link too little (or too much) to get my test working? Or am I looking in the wrong direction?

Comment: What exactly is null? Is it `Request` or `Request.Url` or `Request.Url.Scheme`?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not sure how to determine that. All I receive for an error message is System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object and when I double click on my StackTrace, I am brought to the line I provided above.

Comment: no problem. Download TestDriven.NET; set a breakpoint in the test; right-click, say Test With, Debugger. Inspect the variables, or use `Watch` to figure it out.

Comment: @ashes999 It appears that Request is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, it seems like `Request` is null. I would recommend googling for [how to mock out the request](https://www.google.ca/search?q=asp.net%20mvc%20unit%20testing%20request&aq=f&oq=asp.net%20mvc%20unit%20testing%20request&aqs=chrome.0.57j0l2j62l3.4884&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

I personally love Ninject/Moq. It's a very easy-to-use, powerful combination. You can do something like:

- Create an IHttpRequest interface with whatever you need to mock (in this case, just the `Url` attribute)
- Use Ninject to bind your production app (in global.asax's app-start event) to the real request (`Kernal.Bind<IHttpRequest>().To(HttpRequest)`)
- In your test cases, have a base test class or a global test-run class that binds to your mock class instead (or to a `new Mock<IHttpRequest>()` instance)

You may have to make your interface copy the necessary methods/signatures from the real `HttpRequest` class. If that doesn't work, you will need to create a wrapper class that implements the interface and delegates calls to a real `HttpRequest` instance.

Comment: More so finding out what was throwing the null value. Being able to refine my search helped me push through my test.