# ASP.NET MVC Simple Controller Unit Test

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq

I'm trying to learn unit testing, and have this super simple class, with unit test:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new HomeViewModel
        {
            LogoUrl = this.Url.Content("~/Images/product.png")
       });
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void Index()
{
    Assert.IsNotNull(new HomeController().Index() as ViewResult);
}
```

I'm getting null reference exceptions. It's related to using `this.Url()` without an `HttpContext` in the unit test, I believe.

How can I get the unit test to pass while still using my `this.Url()`? I'm fine with using Moq. :)

Comment: This should be really helpfull http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452418/how-do-i-mock-the-httpcontext-in-asp-net-mvc-using-moq

Comment: I actually did that. I still get a null reference. Without using Reflector (don't have a license), I can't see how this.Url works (i.e. can't see exactly what I need to mock).

Comment: I looked around, and found some interesting things. Take a look at this gist: https://gist.github.com/johnnyreilly/4959924

Comment: And this SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674458/asp-net-mvc-unit-testing-controllers-that-use-urlhelper/675269#675269

Comment: Jordan, please submit your comments as answer and I will mark as accepted. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer can be found here as an example (gist):
https://gist.github.com/johnnyreilly/4959924

Here is a relating Stack Overflow question:
[ASP.NET MVC: Unit testing controllers that use UrlHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674458/asp-net-mvc-unit-testing-controllers-that-use-urlhelper/675269#675269)

Both should help you get on the right tracks.

It comes down to mocking the `HttpRequestBase` and the `HttpResponseBase` so you can mock the actual `HttpContextBase`, which is being used by the `UrlHelper` class.

Answer (score 0):

Realize this is an old question but for others who might stop by, check out Unit Testing Simple ASP.NET MVC Controllers by the always helpful crew at LosTechies: http://lostechies.com/chrismissal/2010/02/05/unit-testing-simple-asp-net-mvc-controllers/